# Llenar input con registro de una tabla que se trae del SQL Server al cargar el formulario evento load en proyecto MVC C# ado.net

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, mvc

Cordial saludo, no he podido encontrar la solución a este inconveniente pido su apoyo y ayuda con este caso. El tema es que cuando carga el formulario cotización de la imagen, en el evento load, el input [TxtCor] = debe cargar el correlativo que se trae de la Base de Datos a través del procedimiento almacenado. En este caso debe traer = 00010. En el input no me muestra el correlativo, he tratado de descartar de diferentes maneras, pero no logro resolver el problema.

El input no recibe el parámetro CotCor que lo llamo de la base de datos y lo llamo del apartado Modelo pero lo raro es que si carga en la consola el correlativo 00010. Como muestra la imagen, al parecer algo estoy haciendo mal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
//-- Código Controlador
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CotCor()
 {
    List<VenCor> lista = VenCotDB.Instancia.ObtCor();
    return Json(new { data = lista }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

```html
//-- Código Modelo
public List<VenCor> ObtCor()
{
    List<VenCor> LisCor = new List<VenCor>();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Conexi.cx))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SpGecCot", con);
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                LisCor.Add(new VenCor()
                {
                    CocCor = dr["CotCor"].ToString(),
                });
            }
            dr.Close();
            return LisCor;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LisCor = null;
            return LisCor;
        }}}
```

```js
  //-- Código Ajax
  var datos = { "CocCor": $("#TxtCor").val(), }
  jQuery.ajax({
     url: '@Url.Action("CotCor", "Ventas")',
     type: "POST",
     data: datos,
     success: function (data) {
         $("#TxtCor").val(data[0].CocCor);
     },
     error: function (error) {
        console.log(error)
     },
      });
```

```html
//-- Procedimiento Almacenado.
Alter Proc SpGecCot
As
   Begin Transaction
          Declare @CorCot Varchar (6)
          Set @CorCot = (Select Isnull(Max(VE_COCREG),0) From VE0005COTC)
          Set @CorCot = Right('00000'+ Cast(Cast(@CorCot As Varchar)+1 As VarChar(6)),5)
          Select @CorCot AS CotCor
     Commit Transaction
  Return
Go

Exec SpGecCot
```

Comment: y como mostras ese campo en la pantalla? porque el error esta ahi, no en todo lo que mostraste ;)

Comment: Hola  Gbianchi, trate de modificar mi código al parecer si lo esta recibiendo el controlador y la vista pero al parecer el problema es en el ajax.

Comment: si data tiene un objeto, que esperas que haga $("#TxtCor").val(data);???

Comment: Me debe devolver el valor y mostrar en el input el valor de la  consulta:  CocCor = dr["CotCor"].ToString(), del modelo del campo "CocCor" que es el correlativo "00001" como muestra el procedimiento almacenado.

Comment: y si en lugar de data, pones data.CorCor, que muestra???

Comment: he intentado pero ahora me sale el input vacio, ya ni siquiera me muestra el [object]

Comment: @WillianEdgarEvangelioAvila, por lo que se ve en la primer imagen `data` es un `array`, por lo que lo correcto sería: `$("#TxtCor").val(data[0].CorCor);`

Comment: Hola Marcos, he intentado como indicas pero no me muestra el correlativo y tampoco me muestra el [Object] que me salía.

Comment: @WillianEdgarEvangelioAvila, por las dudas, tengo un typo debería ser `CocCor` (_yo puse `CorCor`_)

Comment: Hola Marco, disculpa que recién conteste estaba sin internet todo el día, gracias por tus comentarios probé con: success: function (data) {
    $("#TxtCor").val(data[0].CocCor);
},     y no me carga pero en la consola si me muestra que me trae el código, voy a actualizar mis scripts en el apartado para tener la información mas actualizada. Pero hasta el momento no puedo resolver ese problema.

Comment: Hola Marco, he actualizado la información líneas arriba los script que estoy trabajando pero no logro resolver el problema. Ahora en el Modelo estoy llamando al procedimiento almacenado que he generado en en el SQL Server pasando el parámetro CotCor, que lo debo de recibir en el Ajax, pero no tengo éxito. Por favor si me ayudas con esto.